# NTFS Logical Drives Permission Denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, partition, hard-disk, ntfs

I am unable to get into the second (NTFS) drive on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. When I click on the drive icon, I get an error about not having enough permissions.

This is what the **FSTAB** file looks like (of interest are those NTFS entries)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sdb3 :
UUID=4d91ca11-55dd-4624-9d51-e1ded2485b81   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=0CF421D4F421C136   /media/System_Reserved  ntfs    defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
UUID=9486423786421A5E   /media/user-name/9486423786421A5E   ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sdb5 :
UUID=1C74BF6274BF3CF8   /media/user-name/Playground ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=002,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=2A962FC2962F8D7F   /media/user-name/TI105741W0B    ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Ravpower_iPlugmate_90161123320177-0:1   /mnt/usb-Ravpower_iPlugmate_90161123320177-0:1  auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show  0   0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Ravpower_iPlugmate_90161123320177-0:0   /mnt/usb-Ravpower_iPlugmate_90161123320177-0:0  auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show,rw   0   0
```

When I run `lsblk`, I see the following

```
sda             465.8G                                    
└─sda2 ntfs     465.8G /media/user-name/TI105741W0B      TI105741W0B
sdb             931.5G                                    
├─sdb1 ntfs       100M                                    System Reserved
├─sdb2 ntfs     199.9G /media/user-name/9486423786421A5E 
├─sdb3 ext4       100G /                                  
├─sdb4              1K                                    
└─sdb5 ntfs     631.5G /media/user-name/Playground       Playground
```

I have tried changing the permissions on the drive itself, but that didn't affect anything.

```
brw-rw----   1 root       disk      8,  17 Mar 25 13:12 sdb1
brw-rw----   1 root       disk      8,  18 Mar 25 13:12 sdb2
brw-rw----   1 root       disk      8,  19 Mar 25 13:12 sdb3
brw-rw----   1 root       disk      8,  20 Mar 25 13:12 sdb4
brwxrwx-wx   1 user-name  disk      8,  21 Mar 25 13:12 sdb5
```

When I inspect the `/var/log/syslog`, I see some related entries, but am not sure how they can be of use.

```
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop 10qnx: debug: /dev/sdb5 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sdb5 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop 20microsoft: debug: /dev/sdb5 is a FUSE partition
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop 30utility: debug: /dev/sdb5 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop 83haiku: debug: /dev/sdb5 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro on mounted /dev/sdb5
Apr  4 06:20:27 user-desktop os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris on mounted /dev/sdb5
```

I have also tried installing NTFS-Config and using it to automatically configure the drives, but the program was spewing errors from some of its Python code, so I am not sure whether it actually worked as expected or not.

What could be causing this, and how can one fix it?

**Edit:**

I have discovered that when I launch `sudo nautilus` and try to navigate to the drives that way, I am able to access the drives. Furthermore, when I launch the window using `nautilus` (without `sudo`), I again begin getting the permission denied error.

Comment: Which "drive" are you clicking on? The one mounted at `/media/System_Reserved` or the one mounted at `/media/user-name/9486423786421A5E`?

Comment: Clicking on any of the NTFS drives gives that error.

Comment: Have you tried changing the file system type to `ntfs` instead of `ntfs-3g`? Also, open a terminal and `tail -f /var/log/messages` and see what the output is while accessing the drives

Comment: Please see the update for some new information. P.S. I do not seem to have `/var/llog/messages` on my system.

Comment: My mistake. Ubuntu doesn't have `/var/log/messages` by default and now uses `/var/log/syslog`. Did you run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` while partitionsCan you access it via the terminal as `root`? Have you tried adding `rw` in `/etc/fstab` for the `ntfs` partitions and accessing it that way?

Comment: @NasirRiley, I already provided a quote from `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in the original message. Have you seen it?

Comment: @NasirRiley, here is what appears to be the crux of the issue (I created a separate, more pointed post): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224116/ubuntu-18-nautilus-permission-denied-to-ntfs-hard-drives

Answer (score 1):

Don't know your problem still exist.
For NTFS or FAT32 make use of fmask and dmask when mount your partition, don't use umask.

sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Disks app ? It's on all the current buntus and mint. Once there, It 'll show you all of the connected drives (mounted and unmounted). Click on the cog icons for the setting and edit mount options.
Now you can also try this from the Terminal Cli . sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdx1 which would be the drive letter and partition number for the NTFS. That usually works for me.

Comment: I am aware of this app. But edit mount options to what???

Comment: Hello. You edit the mount options to the partition or drive that you highlight and or select while using the Disks app